# NETCore.App WebSockets CancellationToken

Tags: c#, websocket, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am writing a server that receives client data using a **System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocket**.

```
var data = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(requestBuffer, httpContext.RequestAborted);
```

The server should be able to cancel the **ReceiveAsync Task** if the client disconnects without closing the connection (e.g. if the client crash). 
For this reason I used the RequestAborted CancellationToken of the **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext**. But it does not work with it.

I am not sure if I have to implement a CancellationToken with a timeout anyway. On the client side I could implement a "KeepAlive" message that is send within the timeout interval. Could someone show me a implementation for a CancellationToken with a timeout?

**[Update]**

Turns out that I can use this CancellationToken:

```
CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource(10000);
var request = await session.Socket.ReceiveAsync(requestBuffer, source.Token);
```

I assumed that it will cancel the **Task** after 10000 milliseconds and continue execution. Instead it throws an **OperationCanceledException** after 120000 milliseconds. I can live with that.. but I still wonder about the time difference. I keep this question open hoping that someone can tell something about it.

Comment: The `Token` will be automatically set to canceled after 10 seconds which is fine.
However, the actual abort is performed by implementation of the `ReceiveAsync` which clearly does not play well with cancellation since it aborts after 120 seconds.
You cannot do much about that.

Answer (score 2):

Fwiw, I ended up using something like below to "handle" this:

```
var task = socket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, _cts.Token);

while (!task.IsCompleted && !_cts.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    await Task.Delay(100).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```